# INNER JOIN with aggregate functions in my SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to join a new column to my current query that uses aggregate functions. I create this column with a new query that also uses an aggregate function from a different table but I'm not sure if a `JOIN` will work for me since I need to join it to its respective row.

**TABLE A** (employees that are enrolled or were enrolled in a project)

| ID | DEPARTMENT | ENROLLED | PROJECT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MARKETING | Yes | ARQ |
| 2 | MARKETING | Yes | TC |
| 3 | MARKETING | No | ARQ |
| 4 | MARKETING | No | TC |
| 5 | FINANCE | Yes | ARQ |
| 6 | FINANCE | Yes | TC |
| 7 | FINANCE | No | ARQ |
| 8 | FINANCE | Yes | TC |

This table has more departments and more projects, but I simplified.

**TABLE B** (relation with departments and employees)

| ID | DEPARTMENT | TOTAL_EMPLOYEES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MARKETING | 2 |
| 2 | MARKETING | 3 |
| 3 | FINANCE | 4 |
| 4 | FINANCE | 8 |

In my first query I was asked to achieve the following result - using only table A:

```
             (employees enrolled)               (employees not enrolled)
```

| DEPARTMENT | ARQ_E | TC_E | TOTAL_ENROLLED | ARQ_N | TC_N | TOTAL_NOT_ENROLLED | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MARKETING | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| FINANCE | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 |

Using the following query:

```
SELECT  tableA.department, 
        sum(case when enrolled = 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'ARQ' then 1 else 0 end) as ARQ_E,
        sum(case when enrolled = 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'TC' then 1 else 0 end) as TC_E,
        sum(case when enrolled = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as TOTAL_ENROLLED,
        sum(case when enrolled != 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'ARQ' then 1 else 0 end) as ARQ_N,
        sum(case when enrolled != 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'TC' then 1 else 0 end) as TC_N,
        sum(case when enrolled != 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as TOTAL_NOT_ENROLLED,
        count (*) AS Total               
FROM    tableA
GROUP BY tableA.department;
```

My second query gets departments and their total employees from table B:

| DEPARTMENT | TOTAL_EMPLOYEES |
| --- | --- |
| MARKETING | 5 |
| FINANCE | 12 |

Using the following query:

```
SELECT  tableB.department,
        sum(tableB.total_employees) AS TOTAL_EMPLOYEES
FROM tableB
GROUP BY tableB.department;
```

I need to add the column `TOTAL_EMPLOYEES` to my first query, next to `TOTAL` will be `TOTAL_EMPLOYEES`. But it has to be placed with its respective department row. I need this to compare this 2 columns and see how many employees were not assigned to any project.

This is my expected result.

```
                  (employees enrolled)               (employees not enrolled)
```

| DEPARTMENT | ARQ_E | TC_E | TOTAL_ENROLLED | ARQ_N | TC_N | TOTAL_NOT_ENROLLED | TOTAL | T_EMPL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MARKETING | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| FINANCE | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 12 |

I have tried to achieve this using the following query:

```
SELECT  tableA.department, 
        sum(case when enrolled  = 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'ARQ' then 1 else 0 end) as ARQ_E,
        sum(case when enrolled  = 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'TC' then 1 else 0 end) as TC_E,
        sum(case when enrolled  = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as TOTAL_ENROLLED,
        sum(case when enrolled  != 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'ARQ' then 1 else 0 end) as ARQ_N,
        sum(case when enrolled  != 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'TC' then 1 else 0 end) as TC_N,
        sum(case when enrolled  != 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as TOTAL_NOT_ENROLLED,
        count (*) AS Total,
        sum (tableB.total_employees) AS T_EMPL               
FROM    tableA
JOIN    tableB
ON tableA.department = tableB.department
GROUP BY tableA.department;
```

But the numbers I get in my query are completely wrong since the JOINS repeat my rows and my SUMS duplicate.

I don't know if I really need to use a join or a subquery to place my `sum(tableB.department)` in its respective row.

I'm using PostgreSQL but since I'm using Standard 92 any SQL solution will help.

Comment: as you have already both correct solutions, join them after calculating the sum,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue stemmed from inadvertently multiplying rows with the join,
and has already been addressed. See:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)

But use the standard SQL aggregate `FILTER` clause. It's shorter, cleaner, and noticeably faster. See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)
- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27572/3684)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT department
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE enrolled AND project = 'ARQ')     AS arq_e
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE enrolled AND project = 'TC')      AS tc_e
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE enrolled)                         AS total_enrolled
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT enrolled AND project = 'ARQ') AS arq_n
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT enrolled AND project = 'TC')  AS tc_n
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT enrolled)                     AS total_not_enrolled
        , count(*) AS total
   FROM   tableA a
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) a
LEFT JOIN  (  -- !
   SELECT department
        , sum(total_employees) AS total_employees
   FROM   tableB b
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) b USING (department);
```

`enrolled` should be a `boolean` column. Make it so if it isn't. Then you can use it directly. Smaller, faster, cleaner, shorter code.

I replaced the `[INNER] JOIN` with a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` on a suspicion. Typically, you want to keep all results, even if the same department is not found in the other table. Maybe even a `FULL [OUTER] JOIN`?

Also, `USING (department)` as join condition conveniently outputs that column only once, so we can make do with `SELECT *` in the outer `SELECT`.

Finally, subqueries are shorter and faster than CTEs. Not much since Postgres 12, but still. See:

- [Does WITH query store the results of referred tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68528300/does-with-query-store-the-results-of-referred-tables/68529220#68529220)

Comment: Thank you, this is the best answer. Enrolled is already a boolean, I made up these simple tables to explain my situation. I was concerned about keeping the results even if department is not found in the other table, LEFT JOIN worked perfect.
I always try to keep my queries in Standard, that's why I love Postgres. I didn't know how to encapsulate my COUNT with a specific WHERE. Using FILTER I was able to keep it Standard. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Join the results of the two queries, using sub-queries, don't join the tables.

That way you're joining 1 row of enrollment data per department to 1 row of employee data per department.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT  tableA.department, 
          sum(case when enrolled  = 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'ARQ' then 1 else 0 end) as ARQ_E,
          sum(case when enrolled  = 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'TC' then 1 else 0 end) as TC_E,
          sum(case when enrolled  = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as TOTAL_ENROLLED,
          sum(case when enrolled  != 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'ARQ' then 1 else 0 end) as ARQ_N,
          sum(case when enrolled  != 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'TC' then 1 else 0 end) as TC_N,
          sum(case when enrolled  != 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as TOTAL_NOT_ENROLLED,
          count (*) AS Total
               
  FROM    tableA
  GROUP BY tableA.department
)
  AS enroll
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT  tableB.department,
          sum(tableB.total_employees) AS Total_EMPLOYEES
  FROM tableB
  GROUP BY tableB.department
)
  AS employee
    ON employee.department = enroll.department
```

Comment: this will give an error as department is ambiguous

Comment: This solution also worked fine I just needed to switch the " * " for the columns name I want in SELECT. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As the join will multiply the summ, you can first sum the values and then join them

```
WITH CTE1 as (SELECT  tableA.department, 
        sum(case when enrolled  = 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'ARQ' then 1 else 0 end) as ARQ_E,
        sum(case when enrolled  = 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'TC' then 1 else 0 end) as TC_E,
        sum(case when enrolled  = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as TOTAL_ENROLLED,
        sum(case when enrolled  != 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'ARQ' then 1 else 0 end) as ARQ_N,
        sum(case when enrolled  != 'Yes' and tableA.project = 'TC' then 1 else 0 end) as TC_N,
        sum(case when enrolled  != 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as TOTAL_NOT_ENROLLED,
        count (*) AS Total
               
FROM    tableA
GROUP BY tableA.department),
CTE2 as (SELECT  tableB.department,
        sum(tableB.total_employees) AS TOTAL_EMPLOYEES

FROM tableB
GROUP BY tableB.department)
SELECT
CTE1.department,    ARQ_E,  TC_E,   TOTAL_ENROLLED,     ARQ_N,  TC_N,   TOTAL_NOT_ENROLLED,     TOTAL,  T_EMPL,CTE2.TOTAL_EMPLOYEES
FROM CTE1 JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.department = CTE2.department
```